# Iphone : How to get array value in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, json, uitableview, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using google Api for custom search and have done the json Parsing. I succesfully retreived the values from JSON and store that data in Dictionary.

```
 NSArray     *latestdata = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"items"];
```

Now I have two array in it link and title

```
titleArray = [latestdata valueForKey:@"title"];
linkArray = [latestdata valueForKey:@"link"];
```

Now i use the title array to store the title at CellForRowAtIndexpath and i want to use the link for that specified or selected index at DidSelectIndexPathAtRow.

I have already filled the cell by the title array as below

```
cell.textLabel.text = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But now i dont when i select the row at table how can i get the link for that using the link array at didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

What could be the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

> NSLog("Value : %@", [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

I hope `title` is global array.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the same paradigm you set the title with.  You have `indexPath.row` available to you in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

My worry with this is ensuring the arrays are in sync.  Would you no be better served using a Map for the data?  If you are more comfortable, you can store the titles in an array, because parsing that array to build your table is really straight forward.  But how do you know the element in each spot in the title array matches its corresponding member of the link array?  Are you sure `[title objectAtIndex: 1]` matches the desired link in `[link objectAtIndex: 1]`?  Key-value coding will harden this and give you an easier to maintain solution in my opinion.

Good Luck.